# google app engine UDP socket doesn't work

Tags: google-app-engine, sockets, udp

I have tested TCP socket on deployment server, it works.
I test UDP socket on development server and it works, but not on deployment server.
I queried it on browser and after a very long time, it shows:

Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Following is my code:

```
        InetAddress aaddr=InetAddress.getByName("220.152.188.241");
        InetSocketAddress sockAddress=new InetSocketAddress(aaddr, port);
        socket=new DatagramSocket();
        String dataToSend="From google";
        DatagramPacket packet=new DatagramPacket(dataToSend.getBytes(),dataToSend.length(),sockAddress);
        socket.send(packet);
```

I want to make clear this shouldn't be a problem of the destination address reachability, because that doesn't concern udp.
**What's more, I didn't catch any exception. And, what's more, the code takes unusually long time to return.**

Please help!

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a firewall between appengine and the destination. In addition there is a restriction to the port range. Are you in the unrestricted range.  These sort of things will work fine in local dev , but production is different.

Comment: That is not a problem concerning UDP. After all, if anything happened, I capture the exception. But I didn't capture any exception. So this should be a problem of google.

Comment: What on earth to you mean by "That is not a problem concerning UDP" if a firewall somewhere is dropping UDP packets then you will see a time out - ie takes an unusually long time to return. Have you proven destination reachability using UDP from somewhere else outside of your local network ?

Comment: Is your application billable? If you do not have billing enabled/confirmed, than I am pretty sure the Socket API will be locked out.

Comment: As I have posted, TCP socket works in my deployed app.

Comment: Host reachability doesn't matter to UDP.